# PyAudio error while using speechRecognition in python in VS Code

Tags: python, package

Got a **raise AttributeError("Could not find PyAudio; check installation")
AttributeError: Could not find PyAudio; check installation**

*How to fix this issue?*

Comment: Have you installed PyAudio?

Answer (score 0):

```
 pip install pyaudio
```

will work just fine